# Linearly normal embedding and varietes lying on quadrics

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X\subset\Bbb{P}^N$ be a smooth algebraic variety and assume that $X$ is not contained in a hyperplane.

The embedding $i\colon X\hookrightarrow\Bbb{P}^N$ is called *linearly normal* if the linear system on $X$ given by the hyperplane sections is complete. In other words, any divisor in $|\mathcal{O}_X(1)|$ is obtained as $H\cap X$ for some hyperplane $H=\Bbb{P}^{N-1}\subset\Bbb{P}^N$. Cohomologically this means that the injective (restriction) map $H^0(\Bbb{P}^N,\mathcal{O}(1))\to H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(1))$ is an isomorphism.

As far as I understand, when $\dim X=1$, being a linearly normal embedding is equivalent to the following: for some hyperplane $H$, any quadric hypersurface $Q_H$ in $H$ *which contains* $H\cap X$ is the restriction to $H$ of a quadric $Q$ in $\Bbb{P}^N$ containing $X$. Therefore, if $\deg X<\binom{N+1}{2}$ then such a $Q_H$ exists and then $X$ lies on a quadric.

Does this generalize when $\dim X>1$ ?